# Can I use setContent from compose in all activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I faced with problem when i can use setContent in second Activity

```
@Composable
fun BuildContent() {
    val context = LocalContext.current

Button(onClick = {
                val intent = Intent(context, CheatActivity::class.java)
                context.startActivity(intent)
            }) {
                Text(text = "Cheat!")
            }
```

SecondActivity

```
class CheatActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 
    private var answerIsTrue = false 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
            setContent { /*TODO */ } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: P.S: Please use correct tags [android-jetpack-compose]